# Angularjs + MVC + Web API + OWIN cookie authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin

We have a solution that contain 3 parts:
- Angular JS for client side.
- MVC web application to handle SPA.
- Web API for backend functionilities.

We use OWIN "UseCookieAuthentication"  to handle authentication.

The process of being authenticated:
- Angular JS request Web APi service to login.
- Web Api login service check user information and if information is correct it will generate a persistent cookie.
- Web API create a CLaimsPrincipal and put it in the cookie.
- Web API returns the generated cookie token in the response header.
- Angular JS handle authentication using "withcredintials".

The problem we have that some requests go through MVC Application without angular, and in this case MVC application request do not have the"Set-Cookie" header.

I have two quastions:
- first how can i Access the cookie token from my MVC application.
- second can i share the ClaimsPrincipale in both Web API and MVC, then i can see the request as authenticated in MVC.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Cookies aren't well suited for the scenario. Can I inrerest you in taking a look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/ :-)